# Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm

Tags: spring-boot, jjwt

I have an issue. Tried to change the versions (like it says on the internet), but it didn't help.I get this error when i try to deploy project using docker composer

Problem:

```
The method's class, io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm, is available from the following 
 locations:
jar:file:/app/libs/jjwt-0.9.1.jar!/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.class
jar:file:/app/libs/jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar!/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.class
It was loaded from the following location:
    file:/app/libs/jjwt-0.9.1.jar
```

Console:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(Keys.java:84)
```

The following method did not exist:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm.getMinKeyLength()I
```

The method's class, io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/app/libs/jjwt-0.9.1.jar!/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.class
jar:file:/app/libs/jjwt-api-0.11.2.jar!/io/jsonwebtoken/SignatureAlgorithm.class
```

It was loaded from the following location:

```
file:/app/libs/jjwt-0.9.1.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm

This is my pom.xml :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Remove the jjwt artifact. According to the documentation (https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#maven) you only need jjwt-api, jjwt-impl and jjwt-jackson

Comment: when i removed  jjwt artifact i get errors in my code method  Jwts.parserBuilder() not found the method  exist only in jjwt

Comment: The method was probably moved between versions. You might want to delete the old import after you removed the jjwt dependency and your IDE might find the correct new import. The Jwts class still exists and so does the method: https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/Jwts.java

Comment: I provided an answer to properly resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt#maven) you only need the following dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
    <version>0.11.2</version>
</dependency>
```

The missing class / method is  `Jwts.parserBuilder()` [still available](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/jsonwebtoken/Jwts.java) but was probably moved between versions. Removing the import from the class and allowing your IDE to reimport it, should resolve this issue.

(see comments under question for context)